# Portal on MediaWiki

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates, mediawiki-installation

I'm trying to configure Portals on a local MediaWiki bug i'm stuck.

ParserFunction extension is installed.
Portal namespace is configured.

Now i have to copy / import templates from Wikipedia. [Templates imports](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Portals/Templates) I don't understand how to do it ...

Documentation i use to configure this feature : [Documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Portals)

Thank you !

Comment: Download the XML file from the link and use the `Special:Import` page on your wiki.

Comment: Template imports are hard, you need all extensions used by the templates (e.g. [Scribunto](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto)) to be set up with a compatible configuration. You might be better off writing your own templates.

Answer (score 1):

you need to go to the next route

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:Export

in the text box
"Add pages manually"
add the following list

1. Template :! Template: * mp Template: 1x Template: 3x Template:
   Box-footer Template: Box-header Template: Box Portal skeleton
   Template: Browsebar Template: Col-begin Template: Col-break
   Template:    Col-end Template: Cquote Template: Documentation
   Template:    Documentation / docspace Template: Documentation / end
   box Template:    Documentation / end box2 Template: Documentation /
   start box    Template: Documentation / start box2 Template:
   Documentation /    template page Template: Documentation subpage
   Template: Featured    website Template: Fmbox Template: For / aux
   Template: forloop / aux    Template: For loop Template: For loop /
   doc Template: High-risk    Template: Icon Template: Mod Template:
   Multicol Template:    Multicol-break Template: Multicol-end
   Template: Navbar Template:    Numbered subpages Template: Numbered
   subpages / doc Template: Ombox    Template: Ombox / core Template:
   To Template: Portal Template: Portal    / Images / Default Template:
   Portal / Images / Portal Template:    Portal / Images / Main
   Template: Portal / Images / Science Template:    Portal / doc
   Template: Portal other Template: Portal template list    Template:
   Portals Template: Pp-meta Template: Pp-template Template:    Purge
   Template: Purge page Template: Purgepage Template: Rand    Template:
   Random number Template: Random Portal component Template:    Random
   Portal component nominate With Template: Random subpage    Template:
   Selected article Template: Subpage Template: Template other
   Template: Tim Template: Tiw Template: Tl Template: Transclude
   Template: Void Template: Â

·

This will generate an XML file

we are importing from the following path
https: //www.tuwiki.dominio/wiki/Special: import

loads the xml and ready

Answer (score 0):

Where are you doing now?

as you are doing import templates?

I'm doing local instalation, my problem is wikibase, your lua instalation works fine?
what operating system  are you  using?
If you are using linux maybe need a  configure  of permission